# Excel pivot values column to Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, pivot-table

[image]

I have data in Excel pivot and my text data in value column shows number instead of Text . Any one can help me please. In below image of pivot value field red circled:

Comment: your text will not display as a summarized value

Comment: There will be having a text below of raw column,am sure there will be having any method for do this, as per ma contineous search i saw about option vba and using query and all but i dont know how to implement here .Now its taking as count but instead how we can visible same text

Comment: Pivot table make some aggregation (calculation) and give a numeric value back. May be you want to do something like this [here (Pivot in Excel without aggregation, to show text, not numbers?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767117/pivot-in-excel-without-aggregation-to-show-text-not-numbers/32822738#32822738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to click on that, then "Value Field Settings..." -> "Number Format" (in the middle left corner)

but also you must understand that pivot and text values are not good "friends"

Comment: Yess Bes , In "Number Format "category option i try select one by one even Text too but result is not successful . So , what is your opinion is it not at all possible in excel and am not much expert in excel . Thanks

Comment: as I've looked up and tested some random data,  i have noticed that "problem" is in pivot's "Product". Product is not designed to work with text, its for numbers, so it dont know what to do and displays zero :)

Comment: @safwan if you have time look at this tutorial, it will guide you if you have simple texts in you raw data
[link](https://chandoo.org/wp/displaying-text-values-in-pivot-tables-without-vba/)

Comment: @ Bes i check above link and its good one if our column Text is 2 or 3 words, but here i have different Text of more than 100  :O so by making text to number and working not possible and only way i can see there is by VBA and implementing VBA to my file by review above link is much complicated or not possibe for me., Thank you